# $f^{-1}(G\setminus H)=f^{-1}(G)\setminus f^{-1}(H)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, set-theory

Show that if $f:A\to B$ and $G,H$ are subsets of $B$, then
$$f^{-1}(G\setminus H)=f^{-1}(G)\setminus f^{-1}(H)$$

My attemp:

$f^{-1}(G \setminus H)=f^{-1}(G\cap H^{c})$

$=f^{-1}(G)\cap f^{-1}(H^{c})$

$=f^{-1}(G)\cap (f^{-1}(H))^{c}$

$=f^{-1}(G)\setminus f^{-1}(H)$

Can someone kindly confirm whether this is a correct proof? :c

Comment: If you're sure you can use all the steps then it looks fine. I'd expect a double contention proof: left side is contained in the right side and the other way around. But if you already know all the steps then good.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you very much, a question: $f^{-1}((H)^{c})=(f^{-1}(H))^{c}$ is it correct? :c

Comment: Así es...pero la cuestión es si tú puedes utilizar eso en tu demostración...

Comment: @DonAntonio Why are you answering in Spanish?

Comment: Because the student is from Cuernavaca, México...my country. And what I wrote is basically for him, only. Nothing of general interest.

Comment: @DonAntonio Yeah, well, but this is still an English site, no? And the questioner is obviously proficient enough in English to perfectly understand “Yes, but the question is whether you may use this in your proof.” And while I doubt that, on the other side, anyone proficient in English would have trouble understanding that sentence (given the context), one still has to understand it in order to see that it’s not “of general interest”. So, weird move, in my opinion. Anyway, I don’t care too much, just curious.

Comment: @k.stm No, it is not an English site. At least some time ago (and probably still nowadays) it was encouraged to write in whatever language you could, with the condition not to expect too much if the language wasn't English. But there are posts around in german, arabic (!), french, spanish, portuguese and on and on. Of course, posts in English as the huge majority.

Comment: @DonAntonio Didn’t know that. Haven’t seen any non-English posts in quite a while, but know that you mention it, I have a faint memory of stumbling onto one or the other. Still, … switching to Spanish within a perfectly reasonable and intelligible English discussion … weird!

Comment: @k.stm There are many of them around, but still only a very, very small percentage of the total of posts. Just a few minutes ago there was a question in portuguese. Search for it in the first 20 question, sure you will find it. The switcing to spanish is jut to make things smoother for the OP, a more or less new member to this site. Just a matter of being nice, if you will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is a slightly different way to approach it:
\begin{align*}
x\in f^{-1}(G\backslash H) & \Longleftrightarrow f(x) \in G\backslash H\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (f(x)\in G)\wedge(f(x)\not\in H)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x\in f^{-1}(G))\wedge(x\not\in f^{-1}(H))\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x\in f^{-1}(G)\backslash f^{-1}(H)
\end{align*}
and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: This is what I wrote I would be assuming  to be done. +1

Comment: Thank you for the up vote :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Basically, this is because the set difference can be written as intersection and complement, and assume that you are allowed to use the fact that

> if you have a function $f:A\to B$, then $f^{-1}:P(B)\to P(A)$ commutes with union, intersections, and complements.